# Pass boolean type parameter from javascript to android native method got all "false"

Tags: javascript, android, types, parameters, boolean

I use webview in my android app to show H5 website,use javascript to interact with my native java methed.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void TagClick(String tagid,boolean subscribe) {
  Log.i("tagid",""+tagid);
  Log.i("subscribe",""+subscribe);

  ...do something...
}
```

I can get the right tagid,
but with the subscribe of **boolean** type,no matter I pass "true"or"false" in my javascript,I always get "false" here,just don't know why.

Any suggestion would be appriciated.

Comment: If you change boolean to String what do you get?

Comment: I used ""+subscribe in my code   @Pedro Oliveira

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. Change `boolean subscribe` to `String subscribe` and print the value. What do you get?